# Is the Canal des Racó via ferrata route on Majorca open?

Tags: climbing, mallorca

I'm planning a trip to Majorca. I have previously completed a number of Via Ferrata routes and enjoyed them. I wondered if there were any on the island. After some research I have found the [Canal des Racó route](https://ca.wikiloc.com/rutes-via-ferrada/canal-des-raco-pas-des-falco-pas-nou-pas-de-can-boqueta-2616757#wp-2616761) near Soller. However, there seems to be very little information about the route online, and some comments from 2015 suggest that the route is closed, but that this closure is unlawful, or that the route was under construction.

I have also emailed what I think is the local tourism office, who advised me to contact some local tour operators - who have not responded. Does anyone have any more information on whether the route is open and passable at the moment? Or is it still closed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scouting the web for information, mostly in Catalan, the consensus seems to be that the route has been partially closed using gates. However, according to the few guides out there these can be either jumped or circled. Comments on [this Wikiloc article](https://es.wikiloc.com/rutas-via-ferrata/canal-des-raco-pas-des-falco-pas-nou-pas-de-can-boqueta-2616757) suggest that the barriers are illegal and that there is a way around it.

A more complete guide to the ferrata can be found on the [Doblevuit site](http://doblevuit.com/Untitled-215-A.html), and here is the [English translation by Google](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=ca&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fdoblevuit.com%2FUntitled-215-A.html&edit-text=). This guide suggests that it is possible to bypass the barriers. The legal aspects of such practices are not covered. You can try contacting Doblevuit for more information.